# How do I make the yxaes of my python plot to start from bigger and ending to smaller numbers?

Tags: python

I want to change the y axes in my python scatter plot , to start from big values and end to small of my data. How can I do this without setting specific ylim() in order to have a more generalized code?

Comment: Add a reproducable code sample

Comment: See [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).